# In how many ways can a student select at least $2$ and at most $4$ sports?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I'm pretty sure this question has been asked but I didn't get the full answer as I can't reply due to my low reputation. But I'll ask it again.

Each student must play at least 2 sports and no more than 4.

Given that there are 15 possible sports (i.e. including track, road and indoor (e.g.  basketball, squash, swimming etc.)) to choose from, in how many ways may a student pick their sports options upon joining the course

(a) If they have a free choice between all the sports?  and

(b)  If they must play at least one of the three field sports - Hockey, Rugby and Soccer

I have this answer for a)

s == Sport c == Choice s = 15  c = 4

$$15C4 = \frac{15!}{4!(15 - 4)!} = \frac{15!}{4!11!} = 1365$$

Comment: Your answer is hard to parse.  For $a$ I'd have said the answer was the sum $\binom {15}2+\binom {15}3+\binom {15}4=1925$.  I think you just computed $\binom {15}4$ which neglects the cases where the student chooses fewer than $4$.

Comment: Are you [Conor1](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/499329/conor1)?  Your question and the work provided look identical to those posed in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2504943/each-student-must-play-at-least-2-sports-and-no-more-than-4-how-many-ways-may-a).

Comment: No i know who he is though

Comment: @lulu how did you go about coming to that answer? also can you show me how to get to the answer for b). greatly appreciated.

Comment: I followed the same reasoning that I imagine you followed, only you stopped at the case in which the student chooses exactly $4$.  You need to also consider the cases wherein the student chooses $2$ or $3$.  For the other, I think the posted solution from @kccu is hard to improve upon.

Comment: @lulu apologies but ive been stuck since last night, would it be entirely possible if you could show me the solution and how you got to it?

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right track for part (a). You said there are $4$ choices, but the problem states that each student must choose at least two sports and no more than four sports. So the number of choices is $2$, $3$, or $4$. Thus you should compute the number of ways a student can choose $2$ sports, the number of ways a student can choose $3$ sports, and the number of ways a student can choose $4$ sports, and add those all together.

For part (b) I recommend finding the number of ways a student can choose $2$, $3$, or $4$ sports *without choosing a field sport* (so this will change the number of sports they can choose from). If students are required to choose at least one field sport, then we need to exclude all of the choices we just counted. So you should take the answer to part (a) and subtract the number of ways to choose sports without choosing a field sport.

Comment: What about the comment by lulu? they have a different answer from me and now i am unsure whos layout is correct.

Comment: That comment says exactly what I said in the first paragraph of my answer.